# AWS SDK v2 DynamoDB interface for Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I see that the AWS SDK for Go includes a DynamoDB interface, [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbiface/). Does such an interface also exist that implements the V2 SDK Client [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2)?

Comment: @Chandan I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: why you require `dynamodb` interface?

Comment: So I can test around DynamoDB code I write. Besides that, both of these packages are for client library SDKs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing my own, called `DynamoDBAPI`, which can be found in the [xefino/goutils](https://github.com/xefino/goutils) package, in the `awssvc` sub-package, [here](https://github.com/xefino/goutils/blob/main/awssvc/dynamodb/common.go). I did something similar for S3, KMS and SQS as well.

Comment: Btw, your approach is recommended for v2: https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/unit-testing/

Answer (score -1):

This is the official repo that I think you are looking for: [aws-sdk-go-v2/tree/main/service/dynamodb](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/tree/main/service/dynamodb)

Some example for help:

- Creating table programmatically: [Ref](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/main/example/service/dynamodb/createTable/createTable.go#L28)
- Scanning table items: [Ref](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/main/example/service/dynamodb/scanItems/scanItems.go#L47)

Comment: No, this does not answer my question. Specifically, I'm looking for an interface that implements the client contained in that exact package. However, that package includes no such interface, ergo my question.